# Authentication failure while trying to authenticate with OAuth 2 against Microsoft Office365 account

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, office365, multi-factor-authentication

I have a custom developed Windows service that until recently used basic authentication to access an O365 mailbox over POP and pull the contents on a predefined schedule. Microsoft recently announced that they were [dropping the support for basic authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/deprecation-of-basic-authentication-exchange-online#re-enabling-and-opting-out-of-proactive-protection%27) and I should be using OAuth 2 instead. I have followed the steps in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/legacy-protocols/how-to-authenticate-an-imap-pop-smtp-application-by-using-oauth) and my application has the necessary permissions in the Azure portal. I'm still running into an issue.

I can successfully generate the OAuth token. When I try to use said token to authenticate I get "Authentication failure: unknown user name or bad password". No further details are available. I tried Microsoft support but they only referred me to guides I've already followed. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

After three days of scratching my head I finally stumbled upon the answer. Turns out that according to Microsoft ObjectID is different from ObjectID. Because logic! Two different interfaces for the same thing with two different ObjectIDs. You need the one on the right when giving permissions to the mailbox.
[image]